# Custom iterator range function invalid output

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to implement range function to traverse container

```
template<class IterT>
struct iteratorRange {
    IterT begin_;
    IterT end_;

    IterT begin() {
        return begin_;
    }

    IterT end() {
        return end_;
    }
};

template<class T>
iteratorRange<typename vector<T>::iterator>Head(vector<T> v, size_t step) {
    return {begin(v), next(begin(v), min(step, v.size()))};
}

int main() {
   vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
   for (int& i : Head(v, 4)) {
       cout << i  << ' '; 
   }
}
```

I expected

> 1 2 3 4

But received

> 1103219 1109239 3 4

**What is the error?**

Comment: I think the problem is that `vector<T> v` is a copy and your iterators refer to that copy's elements. But the copy doesn't exist anymore when you `cout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class T>
iteratorRange<typename vector<T>::iterator>Head(vector<T>& v, size_t step) {
    return {begin(v), next(begin(v), min(step, v.size()))};
}
```

Instead of Head taking vector v by value, it should take a reference. 
This fixes your problem.